3D cartoon involving a lion with a crown on his head, a crystal, and artifacts that need to be found
The cartoon was made in 3D and was broadcast in 2010-2014.
The main character is a boy or a girl, I don't remember exactly, maybe both. Each episode was based on the search for the missing "artifact" that flew out of a huge yellow crystal that was located in the middle of the forest. As soon as the crystal cracked, some object like a watch flew out of it, and it needed to be found urgently. At the same time, the crystal changed its color to green, red, and so on. Also in this cartoon, there was a lion with a crown on his head, who told the children what to look for.

Is this Animalia (2007–2008)...?

Animalia tells the story of two human children, Alex and his friend Zoe, who stumble into the magical library which transports them to the animal-inhabited world of Animalia.

It's a 3D-animated series based on Graeme Base's 1986 picture book of the same name.
The protagonists are a human boy and girl named Alex and Zoe. In the first episode, they enter a public library and find a portal that transports them to Animalia, a kingdom in another world populated by talking animals and ruled by a lion named Livingstone. He doesn't wear a crown but sometimes wears a gold headpiece with a pair of gold binoculars attached to it.


Animalia - S01E23 - "Nothing But the Truth"

Animalia is powered by the Core, a huge magical gemstone located in Animalia City's library. The Core is normally yellow, but a crack has recently appeared in it and it now sometimes changes colour and shoots 'core spores' into the sky, which then land somewhere in the jungles or mountains surrounding Animalia City.
Each core spore contains a unique object symbolising some aspect of Animalia, such as language, time and dreams. Alex and Zoe are called upon by Livingstone to find and return these objects to the Core as soon as possible to remedy the detrimental effects caused by their absence.
For example, in episode 3, the Core shoots out the 'time spore,' the absence of which disrupts the flow of time in Animalia, although Alex and Zoe seem immune to this. When they find and open the time spore, it contains a pocket watch.
The Core is visible at around the 0:35 mark in the video below.



